How do you Get tick value for symbols in Mql5 Code?
When I am trading on different symbols in the forex market,
At the time of risk calculation ,
I can't calculate the risk correctly because I don't know Tick Value.
How can I find out how much dollars I will take for each pip movement?

in your chart, you can use this bot in mql5 and run on your chart.
Github : https://github.com/MaryamAzhdari/BotInfo

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|   Info.mq5                                                       |
//|   Copyright 2024, MetaQuotes Ltd.                                |
//|   https://www.mql5.com                                           |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
#property copyright "Copyright 2024, MetaQuotes Ltd."
#property link      "https://www.mql5.com"
#property version   "1.00"
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Expert initialization function                                   |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int OnInit()
  {
//---
   
//---
   return(INIT_SUCCEEDED);
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Expert deinitialization function                                 |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnDeinit(const int reason)
  {
//---
   
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Expert tick function                                             |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnTick()
  {
//double tick_value = MarketInfo(_Symbol,MODE_TICKVALUE);
double tick_value = SymbolInfoDouble(_Symbol,SYMBOL_TRADE_TICK_VALUE);
   Comment("\n\n\n\n",
   "TickValue = " ,tick_value);
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+

